# how can i select ONLY the first row of this dbml query?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

this is my original query

```
public UserChallenge GetUserChallenge(int userId, int challengeId)
    {
                   var result = from userChallenge in DataContext.UserChallenges
                   where userChallenge.UserId == userId && userChallenge.ChallengeId == challengeId
                   select userChallenge;
```

here is the modified query

```
                       var result = from userChallenge in DataContext.UserChallenges
                       where userChallenge.ChallengeId == challengeId
                       select userChallenge;
```

there is more than 1 userChallenge's that hold that ChallengeId.  How can I select only the first one ?

Comment: @Bill, did you remove the accepted answer when you reverted the question text?

Comment: @Ellesedil No, moderators can't remove the accept check mark without deleting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check out FirstOrDefault.

```
var result = (from userChallenge in DataContext.UserChallenges
               where userChallenge.UserId == userId && userChallenge.ChallengeId == challengeId
               select userChallenge).FirstOrDefault();
```

But in the long run, it might be more helpful to determine a way to uniquely identify your records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` to get the first item in the list. `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` if no item is found, whereas `First` fails with "Sequence contains no elements" error.

```
var result = (from userChallenge in DataContext.UserChallenges
  where userChallenge.ChallengeId == challengeId
  select userChallenge).FirstOrDefault();
```